# Octal number equations

Tags: octal

So I'm reading a book on how binary bits are converted into octal numbers.
When trying to explain the concept, they give this equation

N= S(...((d8)2^8+(d7)2^7+(d6)2^6)+((d5)2^5+(d4)2^4+(d3)2^3)+((d2)2^2+(d1)2^1+d0))

or

N= S(...((d8)2^2 +(d7)2+(d6))2^6 + ((d5)2^2 +(d4)2^1 + (d3))2^3 + ((d2)2^2+(d1)2^1+d0))

d represents the digit found within the bit, e.g. if the least significant bit was 1, then (d0) would be 1.

I understand all of this, but they elaborate further saying that the parenthesized expressions ((d8)2^2 +(d7)2+(d6)) are coefficients of base 8 digits, N=S((d2)8^2+(d1)*8+(d0)).

Can someone explain what they mean by the parenthesized expressions being coefficients of base8 digits?

Comment: Which book is this? Octal numbers are no different than any other number-base system. Binary is converted to decimal by multiplying the binary digit by two raised to the nth power, where n is the zero-based position of the digit from right to left. Now octal-based is the digit multiplied by 8 raised to the nth power, where n is the zero-based position from right to left. However, 8 is the same as 2 raised to the third power. Therein lies the relationship.

Comment: So I understand the concept of bases and how it affects numerical representation but these equations sort of confused me and I couldnt really decipher what the book was trying to say-- the idea of the parenthesized portion being a coefficient of base 8 digits is what I am referring to. What does the book mean by that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The digits *d<sub>i</sub>* are the binary digits of the number.  We can compute the number from its binary digits like this:

*n* = ∑ <sub>*i*</sub> 2<sup>*i*</sup> *d<sub>i</sub>* = 2<sup>0</sup> *d*<sub>0</sub> + 2<sup>1</sup> *d*<sub>1</sub> + 2<sup>2</sup> *d*<sub>2</sub> + ⋯

(This is in fact what defines “binary”, if we add the condition that the digits are integers and 0 ≤ *d<sub>i</sub>* < 2 for all *i*.)

Suppose we name the octal digits of the number *o<sub>j</sub>*.  We can compute the number from its octal digits like this:

*n* = ∑ <sub>*j*</sub> 8<sup>*j*</sup> *o<sub>j</sub>* = 8<sup>0</sup> *o*<sub>0</sub> + 8<sup>1</sup> *o*<sub>1</sub> + 8<sup>2</sup> *o*<sub>2</sub> + ⋯

(This is what defines “octal”, if we add the condition that the digits are integers and 0 ≤ *o<sub>j</sub>* < 8 for all *j*.)

Now let's look back at the binary equation.  The first step is the trickiest.  We will change the way the subscript is used so that each term of the summation uses three binary digits:

*n* = ∑ <sub>*j*</sub> 2<sup>3 *j* + 0</sup> *d*<sub>3 *j* + 0</sub> + 2<sup>3 *j* + 1</sup> *d*<sub>3 *j* + 1</sub> + 2<sup>3 *j* + 2</sup> *d*<sub>3 *j* + 2</sub>

Convince yourself that that equation computes the same *n* as the first equation I gave.

I assume you know that *x*<sup>*a* + *b*</sup> = *x<sup>a</sup>* *x<sup>b</sup>*.  So we can separate those 2<sup>3 *j* + *b*</sup> coefficients like this:

*n* = ∑ <sub>*j*</sub> (2<sup>3 *j*</sup> 2<sup>0</sup>) *d*<sub>3 *j* + 0</sub> + (2<sup>3 *j*</sup> 2<sup>1</sup>) *d*<sub>3 *j* + 1</sub> + (2<sup>3 *j*</sup> 2<sup>2</sup>) *d*<sub>3 *j* + 2</sub>

Then we can factor out the 2<sup>3 *j*</sup> term like this:

*n* = ∑ <sub>*j*</sub> 2<sup>3 *j*</sup> (2<sup>0</sup> *d*<sub>3 *j* + 0</sub> + 2<sup>1</sup> *d*<sub>3 *j* + 1</sub> + 2<sup>2</sup> *d*<sub>3 *j* + 2</sub>)

I assume you also know that *x*<sup>*a b*</sup> = (*x<sup>a</sup>*)<sup>*b*</sup>.  So we can split the 2<sup>3 *j*</sup> term like this:

*n* = ∑ <sub>*j*</sub> (2<sup>3</sup>)<sup>*j*</sup> (2<sup>0</sup> *d*<sub>3 *j* + 0</sub> + 2<sup>1</sup> *d*<sub>3 *j* + 1</sub> + 2<sup>2</sup> *d*<sub>3 *j* + 2</sub>)

And we can simplify 2<sup>3</sup> to 8:

*n* = ∑ <sub>*j*</sub> 8<sup>*j*</sup> (2<sup>0</sup> *d*<sub>3 *j* + 0</sub> + 2<sup>1</sup> *d*<sub>3 *j* + 1</sub> + 2<sup>2</sup> *d*<sub>3 *j* + 2</sub>)

Compare this to the formula for computing the number from its octal digits, which I repeat here:

*n* = ∑ <sub>*j*</sub> 8<sup>*j*</sup> *o<sub>j</sub>*

So we can conclude this:

*o<sub>j</sub>* = 2<sup>0</sup> *d*<sub>3 *j* + 0</sub> + 2<sup>1</sup> *d*<sub>3 *j* + 1</sub> + 2<sup>2</sup> *d*<sub>3 *j* + 2</sub>

For example, let's take *j* = 2:

*o<sub>2</sub>* = 2<sup>0</sup> *d*<sub>3×2 + 0</sub> + 2<sup>1</sup> *d*<sub>3×2 + 1</sub> + 2<sup>2</sup> *d*<sub>3×2 + 2</sub> = 2<sup>0</sup> *d*<sub>6</sub> + 2<sup>1</sup> *d*<sub>7</sub> + 2<sup>2</sup> *d*<sub>8</sub>